# Linq Select Error

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

Here is my code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("drivers");
```

this is the normal code:

```
var q = from drivers in ds.Tables[0]
        .Select("EmployeeNumber = " + "0000008823")
        select (drivers["EmployeeNumber"] + " - " + drivers["Name"]);
```

the same code, but this code gives an error:

```
var q = from drivers in ds.Tables[0]
        .Select("EmployeeNumber = " + "0000000023")
        select (drivers["EmployeeNumber"] + " - " + drivers["Name"]);
```

> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <drivers>
    <Driver>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <EmployeeNumber>0000000023</EmployeeNumber>
    </Driver>
    <Driver>
      <Name>Mike</Name>
      <EmployeeNumber>0000008823</EmployeeNumber>
    </Driver>
</drivers>
```

Comment: You might want to add the actual error you get from running the code. Is it a runtime error?

Comment: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.

Comment: Phil, have you tried with "0000000023"?

Comment: you could use xml serialization to make it clearer.

Comment: @БахрамХоджаев: You should edit the error into your question - and *always* specify the error when you're asking a question like this.

Comment: Yes I copied your code into LINQPad - no error for either query.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was this

```
var q = from drivers in ds.Tables[0]
        .Select("EmployeeNumber = '" + employeeNumber + "'")
        select (drivers["EmployeeNumber"] + " - " + drivers["Name"]);
```

but I do not know why I got that error before

Comment: You have quoted the number making it a string.

Comment: the single quotation marks makes the employeenumber a string. (->'<-" + employeeNumber + "->'<-")

Comment: My guess is that with leading zeroes it tried to parse the number `08823` as octal, but with digits >=8 in it, it was an invalid integer so it typed it as string. With a valid octal number (`023`), it typed it as an integer (with value 35)

Comment: Stian Standahl, employee number was a string in a double qoutes
        .Select("EmployeeNumber = " + "0000000023")

Comment: Er... after a coffee my octal tells me that `35` in my above comment should be `19` :)

Comment: Joachim Isaksson, parameter employeeNumber in method is string

Comment: Yes, when quoted as you did now, it's a string. When unquoted, `Select` seems to attempt a best guess at the type.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think going into Linq to Dataset way?

```
var q2 = from drivers in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
         where drivers.Field<string>("EmployeeNumber") == "0000000023"
         select (drivers["EmployeeNumber"] + " - " + drivers["Name"]);
```

Additonal benefit, you can easily move to Linq2Sql or Linq2EF, if you filter the rows with a standard 'where' instead of the Select() method of the datatable.

Comment: this approach works fine, ok, thanks
but what was the problem in my source

Comment: well... I was unable to reproduce

Comment: xeondev, here is my simple project http://dl.dropbox.com/u/149591425/ConsoleApplication2.zip

Comment: As others said DataTable.Select(string) method tries to evaluate filterexpression "EmployeeNumber = 0000000023", and concludes the parameter as an int. I don't know how it is working internally. Valid filter syntax is here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/